# Sails.js: how to do updatedDate for records?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to figure out how to get an updatedDate record to save into entries on my basic MySQL-enabled CRUD application. I have this in my `models/user.js` for the createdDate:

```
createdData: {
            type: 'string',
            columnType: 'datetime'
}
```

I wanted something like this for the updatedDate:

```
createdData: {
            type: 'string',
            columnType: 'datetime',
            value: date(),
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes), there is a function within Sails.js for `updatedAt` but this doesn't specify which field it sends that `date();` calculation to. Is there something I am missing for creating an `updatedAt` column for updated records?

Answer (score 1):

`createdAt` and `updatedAt` (along with ID) are base attributes that are included in all of your models by default. That means `updatedAt` is its own field created automatically by Sails.
 `updatedAt` simply marks the most recent time any changes were made to that entry. 
If you want to change the format this data is saved in you can do that in your `config/models.js` file.